# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '%' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an Object Data Source which pulls information from the database where if we don'd have a value for this particular parameter then we want to get all records. So I have a LIKE statement and I'm using a wildcard to return all entries, but this is giving me the error message

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '%' to data type int.

The table structure for the relevant column is:

```
[columnName] VARCHAR(50)
```

The SQL is something similar to:

```
SELECT [columns] from [table] where [column] LIKE @param
```

Then in VB I add the parameter:

```
Dim sessionParam As New Parameter
sessionParam.Name = "param"
sessionParam.DefaultValue = "%"
sessionParam.Type = TypeCode.String
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(sessionParam)
```

So far I've tried casting the parameter value, casting the column, using dbType for the parameter instead of type, but nothing seems to work and I just get the same error. I suspect the column is reading as an int as this column is a mix of values so some are numbers, some are text, therefore SQL is making the 'educated guess' that that value needs to be an int

Comment: It's definitely, 100% a VarChar with 50 characters

Comment: Just curious, have you tried your query using a third party query tool?

Comment: I have and it works fine so I would say the issue is with the parameter somewhere?

Comment: SQL does not makes guesses, can you check if SqlDataSource1 is bound to any control or datatable that has int for this column in stead of string ?

Comment: It doesn't no - everything pointing to that column indicates string / varchar - and when I say guess I mean that in some circumstances SQL evaluates the top x amount of rows and evaluates them to get a datatype - not sure if that is what's happing here, but I know it can happen

Comment: Your table structure says "columnName" but your query says "columns".

Comment: Try `sessionParam.DefaultValue = "'%'"`

Comment: @Duston That just becasue they're examples, the actual column names match - Anton - doesn't work - same error

Comment: Side note... in your post you state `[columnName]` is a `varchar` but in your `select` you are looking at `[column]` instead. Did you mean to say `where [columnName] like @param`?

Comment: Are you able to post a script that reproduces the issue?   Right now we have to take your word that all the columns involved are the varchar datatypes, and I for one am skeptical.

Comment: Another thing to try would be to use a profiler on your server. See if you can verify that the query that is being used on the server is the query that you expect. Using SQL Server Management studio this is possible, but I'm  not sure what your backend is.

Comment: @Web Develop Wolf : You can also use `SQL Profiler` to capture actual sql sent by the application to your sql server. If this sql query looks OK - try running it manually from Management Studio [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2040/use-sql-server-profiler-to-trace-database-calls-from-third-party-applications/] [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx] [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `LIKE` if the parameter is `NULL`, try this instead.

```
SELECT [columns] from [table] where @param is null or [column] = @param
```

If you pass in a `NULL` parameter everything is returned. If it isn't null, then only where the column matches the parameter will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '%' to data type int

Is pretty clear that you have a datatype issue.  And the wildcard of `'%'` is certainly not a `integer`.  You are probably having the issue because the `column` in `where [column] LIKE @param` is probably an `integer`.  So even though you identify the parameter as `string` it is still trying to do an `integer` to `string` comparison.

So you are comparing like `WHERE Integer LIKE String` and that throws a datatype conversion error because SQL will automatically try to `convert` your `string` to an `integer`.

To solve if you want to search for a number as a string which doesn't seem like a good idea you would do something like:

```
WHERE CAST([column] AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE @param.
```

Comment: I already tried casting the column but still got the exact same error

Comment: you need to show us your actual relevant code then because from your example to your error statement there can only be a couple options you are either comparing an integer column to a string or trying to compare string to integer.  Are you perhaps using a case statement in your select that could be causing the conversion issue instead?  You need to put in your actual relevant code because you simplification has likely removed your issue